# Set several domains to several dynamic URLs

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns, cross-domain

I have a tiny web app that generates content like tiny webpages with a specific urls like:

```
mypage.com/content/lorem-ipsum/

mypage.com/content/foo-bar-baz/
```

The HTML of that pages don't really exist, the content is loaded from a database and structured with PHP, and the images are in the webserver, of course.

and so on...

I want to buy some domains and associate to each semantic URLs like:

`loremipsum.com` loads the content of: `mypage.com/content/lorem-ipsum/`

`foobar.com` loads the content of: `mypage.com/content/foo-bar-baz/`

I don't want a redirect, I want that the URL doesn't change (i.e `loremipsum.com`) not redirected to the `mypage.com/content/lorem-ipsum/`

My server is `APACHE`, is there some  `RewriteRule`  rule that can do it?

How can I achieve this? or some similiar alternatives if it not possible :(

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve all the domains from the same host and then use mod_rewrite like this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =loremipsum.com
RewriteRule ^$ content/lorem-ipsum/ [L]
```

That should get you started. Let me know what else you need to know.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I'm newbie with the concepts of domains. First of all, thanks for answering *thumbs up*. How can I associate `loremipsum.com` to my hosting, just loggin in my registrar and change the DNS to the my hosting's DNS? Which are the steps?

Comment: Well, yes, changing the DNS to your host's settings is going to be part of it, but the server also needs setting up to serve that domain for your site. That depends on the setup of your host. I suggest asking them how to do that for their setup.

Comment: I meant, my webserver allow 1 website, can I buy a domain in my country registrar and set it up the DNS and then, set up the `Mod-rewrite` rule to make that redirection?

Comment: `...but the server also needs setting up to serve that domain for your site...`  how can I do this?

Comment: So I'm suggesting that you have multiple domains served by the same website, and then use the code above to make it do what you're asking. You can't do anything unless you can have multiple domains served by your site. DNS doesn't point to a website, it points to a server. That server must be aware of the domain and know which site to serve for it. Ask your host how you can have multiple domains served by your one site. If you can't do that then this is not going to be possible on that host.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but maybe must I create a CNAME record or sort of in my hosting zone editor? I use cPanel v. 62.0.17

Comment: Whatever you do in DNS, the web server still needs to be configured to serve the site. DNS only points your domain at a web server, the server must know how to respond. In cPanel the *Parked Domains* feature should do it for you. Is there a problem with asking your hosting company?

Comment: There is no a problem, but they said me that I must upgrade my hosting plan, because my hosting is for only 1 website. But I don't want to store files, I don't want aditional FTP accounts or a subfolders in my `/` I just want buy domains in my registrar and make a `redir`. But I don't know how to figure out, and they (the hosting support will not tell, because they want I upgrade my plan). And please forgive my horrible way to write english.

Comment: Did you look for "Parked Domains" in your cPanel?

Comment: If you mean "Aliases" option, I can only have 1 :/ The server's support tell me that if I want more I need to upgrade the hosting service.

Comment: But I can add records (A, AAAA, CNAME, SRV, TXT, MX)

Comment: Then you need to upgrade the hosting service or move elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for try helping me